# Is there an easier way of creating/choosing related data with ActiveAdmin?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

Imagine I have the following models:

```
class Translation < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :localizations
end

class Localization < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :translation
end
```

If I do this in ActiveAdmin:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Localization do
  form do |f|
    f.input :word
    f.input :content
  end 
end
```

The association for word will only allow me to choose from existing words. However, I'd like to have the option of creating a new word on the fly. I thought it may be useful to accept nested attributes in the localization model ( but then, I will only have the option of creating a Word, not selecting from existing ones ). How can I solve this problem?

Comment: In your ActiveAdmin how would you like to determine which is the current Translation - choosing it from a menu or stored in params (passed by url) ?

Comment: I should be able to either select it from a menu, or create a new translation and a new localization ( all at once )

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think you can try using virtual attribute for this

Example(not tested)

```
class Localization < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :new_word #virtual attribute 
  attr_accessible :word_id, :content, :new_word
  belongs_to :translation
  before_save do
     unless @new_word.blank?
       self.word = Word.create({:name =>  @new_word})
     end
  end
end
```

The main idea is to create and store new Word instance  before saving localization and use it instead of word_id from drop-down.

```
ActiveAdmin.register Localization do
  form do |f|
    f.input :word
    f.input :content
    f.input :new_word,  :as => :string

  end 
end
```

There is great rails-cast about virtual attributes http://railscasts.com/episodes/167-more-on-virtual-attributes