# How to add a custom column which is not present in table in active admin in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, customization, activeadmin

in my rails application, i have installed `active admin`. in `users index` page, by default, `all columns` are getting displayed(User table columns). I want to add a `custom column called "become user" in this users index view` (which is not a column in User's table). under this `column` i want to display `user name` as a `hyperlink`. up on clicking of that link the `admin` will be logged in to that particular user account. in order to implement this switching feature, i am using `switch user` gem. how to customise this view in `Active Admin`? and how to generate a link for all users in active admin

```
ActiveAdmin.register User do

  permit_params do
    permitted = [:email, :fname, :lname, :phone]
    #   permitted << :other if resource.something?
    #   permitted
end

  # Filterable attributes on the index screen
  filter :email
  filter :fname
  filter :lname
  filter :phone
  filter :current_sign_in_at
  filter :created_at


  # Customize columns displayed on the index screen in the table
  index do
    selectable_column
    id_column
    column :email
    column :fname
    column :lname
    column :phone
    column :current_sign_in_at
    # column :sign_in_count
    column :created_at

    # actions
  end

  form do |f|
    inputs 'Details' do
      input :email
      input :password
      input :fname
      input :lname
      input :phone
    end
    actions
  end

  controller do
  end

end
```

Comment: Can you paste your `ActiveAdmin` setup for `User` model?

Comment: Hello John, you always paste questions like this without code. Please go read the rules from this community https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask you pasted in the past a similar question, broad and did not include code example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46033523/how-to-authenticate-the-user-from-the-email and also this other one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44971139/signin-user-upon-clicking-the-link-in-email-automatically-in-rails-application

Comment: Hi, @AntonTkachov. I updated the question with code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to go with approach, that is called virtual attribute in your model:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  def become_user
    "I am a virtual attribute of this user"
  end
end
```

Then add it to your ActiveAdmin setup

PS: check this for some additional details: [Is there an easier way of creating/choosing related data with ActiveAdmin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13100569/is-there-an-easier-way-of-creating-choosing-related-data-with-activeadmin)